# discontinuous image in UITableView background

Tags: iphone, uitableview, photoshop

I have been using a photoshop design for my iPhone App. I've sliced a 320 by 480 image into four horizontal parts and set them as the backgorund of four continous cells of a `UITableView`. But they don't look continous ... a tinyyy gap is visible in the boundary of the cells. Anyone got a better idea or work around ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is a 1px gap between each UITableViewCell for the separator. If you don't want it you can set the separator to none.

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```